# Drop a table if it exists in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to drop a table only if it exists , in C# with MySql .

Consider the following code:

```
namespace CSharpMySqlSample
{
   class Example2
   {
      static void Main()
      {
         String str = @"server=localhost; database=sakila; uid=root;                password=root;";
         MySqlConnection con = null;
         try
         {
            con = new MySqlConnection(str);
            con.Open(); //open the connection        
            String cmdText = @"drop table `sakila`.`testable` if exists"; // this one drops a table 
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute the mysql command
         }
         catch (MySqlException err)
         {
            String outp = err.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.ToString());
         }
         finally
         {
            if (con != null)
            {
               con.Close(); //close the connection
            }
         } //remember to close the connection after accessing the database
      }
   }
}
```

It produced :

> "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'if exists' at line 1\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int64& insertedId)\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&
>   affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
>   force)\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n   at
>   CSharpMySqlSample.Example2.Main()

So what's wrong with the query ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sakila.testtable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
String cmdText = @"IF OBJECT_ID('sakila'.'testable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE 'sakila'.'testable'";
```

Also make sure that the database user which your program runs under has the neccessary permission to drop tables, but you'll see that right away when you try to run this :-)

Comment: Didn't know MySQL had `OBJECT_ID()` function

Comment: Damn.  For some reason I thought he was using T-SQL (MS-SQL Server).  My bad.

Answer (score 2):

`if exists` needs to go before the table name. Read the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-table.html)....

```
String cmdText = @"drop table if exists 'sakila'.'testable'";
```

Answer (score 1):

just type:

```
String cmdText = @"drop table `sakila`.`testable`";
```

without "if exists"

and don't add anything in **catch** so you will have table deleted or not depends on if it exists or not without any errors :)