# Remove MySql database table on remote server from C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, remote-server

If I can create `MySql` database table on remote server from `C#` desktop application `string createTableQuery = string.Format(table, tableName);` and  `var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(createTableQuery, conn);` Then how do I remove `table` from `MySql` database by `tableName`

Any guide, advice or example would helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write an inline query with DROP TABLE TABLENAME command and pass it as an argument to your MYSQLCOMMAND. If the user has necessary permission, It will drop the table.
[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848335/drop-a-table-if-it-exists-in-c&ved=2ahUKEwjPzLqh6p3hAhVb6XMBHW43CdIQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw15XADAp1GRah8HxDwB5gFY&cshid=1553535447582)